# Paperclip SEND method, Person model missing required attr_accessor for 'identity_photo_file_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to use paperclip to attach things. In this case an identity photo to the person model.

So, I have this in my Gemfile:

```
gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

my person.rb

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 has_attached_file :identity_photo
end
```

my parameters are coming like this:

```
Parameters: {person_identity_photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000090cc728 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20141230-8243-18uvxyd>, @original_filename="asdasd.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"registration_form[person_identity_photo]\"; filename=\"asdasd.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}}
```

I'm delegating fields in a class, so at the end what I'm doing is:

```
 self.send(field, value)
```

with that line I'm sending the parameter to the model. But I'm getting this:

```
 Person model missing required attr_accessor for 'identity_photo_file_name'
```

So, I'm not sure how to handle that exception, any ideas?

Comment: Have you run the [required migrations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#migrations) to ensure that the `identity_photo_file_name` column is in the `people` table?

Comment: what will be changed if you add that `attr_accessor` explictly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occured mainly when you don't have all four required columns in your database. If this is the case try run below commands :

```
rails generate paperclip person identity_photo
rake db:migrate
```

If this is not the case then you might need to whitelist `:identity_photo_file_name` in your permit params.

```
class PersonController < ApplicationController
  .....
  private
    def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:xxxxx, :identity_photo, :identity_photo_file_name)
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't have a personcontroller, as I wrote, I just have a registration controller, and I'm reciving that paramater like this `code` {person_identity_photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000090cc728 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20141230-8243-18uvxyd>, @original_filename="asdasd.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"registration_form[person_identity_photo]\"; filename=\"asdasd.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}} I'm just sending parameters using 'send' to the model. Btw Already check the migrations and everything it's ok.

Comment: So you need to pass them in persons_attributes in registration controller something like :persons_attributes => {:identity_photo, :identity_photo_file_name}